# Django's Inline Admin's Delete checkbox always returns true

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've had to overload the save_formset method inside of my django admin.  When attempting to detect if the Delete? checkbox was checked, it always returns True.

I've got an inline admin class: DataPoolInline
Which is inlined by: DataAdmin

Inside DataAdmin, I overload the save_formset:

```
  def save_formset( self, request, form, formset, change):
    formset.save()
    idx = 0
    for f in formset.forms:
      if isinstance( f.instance, DataPool ):
        DataPool.save_model( self, request, f.instance, f, change, idx )
        idx += 1
```

Inside the static method DataPool.save_model:

```
  #Used to save a model from the admin
@staticmethod
def save_model( adm, request, obj, form, change=None, idx=None ):
    #If delete was in there, then stop
  if 'DELETE' in form.fields and form.fields['DELETE']:
    print("Quiting because delete is selected")
    return

    #Save my object
  obj.save()
```

The Quiting because delete is always printed, not sure how to actually detect what the value of the field of Delete? is.

**Note**

The form.fields['DELETE'] field is a BooleanField.  Am I missing something simple working with BooleanFields?  I've attempted to wrap it in bool() but it always returns True.

Comment: Isn't `form.fields['DELETE']` a dictionary? Try printing out the value of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check form data in the `cleaned_data` dictionary instead of `fields`:

```
if 'DELETE' in form.fields and form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE'):
```